# fit background around node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create two backgrounds. The first one will include the following nodes : rnc1, 1 and 2, and the second one will include rnc2, 3,4.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{chains}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, chains, fit}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}      

\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            scale=0.8,
            transform shape,
            %show background rectangle,
            background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
            box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
              ]
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](cn)[minimum width=10cm,minimum height=2.4cm]{Core network};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm](fill)[minimum height=1cm, below =1cm of cn]{Radio Network subsystem};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](rnc1)[minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.4cm,  left =1cm of fill]{Radio network controller};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](rnc2)[ minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.4cm, right =1 of fill]{Radio network controller};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm, ](fill2)[minimum height=1cm, below =1cm of rnc2]{};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](4)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, right =1 of fill2]{Node B};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](3)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, left =1 of fill2]{Node B};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm, ](fill3)[minimum height=1cm, below =1cm of rnc1]{};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](2)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, right =1 of fill3]{Node B};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](1)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, left =1 of fill3]{Node B};
            \node [label=below:User equipement] (pc)[below= 1cm of fill3]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b} };
            \node [label=below:User equipement] (phone)[below= 1cm of fill2]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
            \draw[thick,->](cn)--node[]{}(rnc1);
            \draw[thick,->](cn)--node[]{}(rnc2);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc1)--node[]{}(1);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc1)--node[]{}(2);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc2)--node[]{}(3);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc2)--node[]{}(4);
            \draw[thick,->](1)--node[]{}(pc);
            \draw[thick,->](4)--node[]{}(phone);

            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \path (rnc1) -- (1) coordinate[pos=0.95](aux1) (2) coordinate (aux2) (rnc1) coordinate (aux3)
            (rnc1) coordinate (aux4) (3) coordinate (aux5) (4) coordinate (aux6);
            \node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,draw,
            fit=(aux1) (aux2) (aux3)]{};
            \node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,draw,
            fit=(aux4) (aux5) (aux6)]{};
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

With the output :[image: output]

In fact, I was hopping for something like this:

[image]

But the rectangles behind, and automatically fitting if I move the nodes.

Like explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457729/drawing-network-schema).

I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Anything wrong with `\node[draw,thick,fit=(rnc1)(1)(2)]{};
   \node[draw,thick,fit=(rnc2)(3)(4)]{};`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\begin{document}      

\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            scale=0.8,
            transform shape,
            %show background rectangle,
            background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
            box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
              ]
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](cn)[minimum width=10cm,minimum height=2.4cm]{Core network};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm](fill)[minimum height=1cm, below =1cm of cn]{Radio Network subsystem};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](rnc1)[minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.4cm,  left =1cm of fill]{Radio network controller};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](rnc2)[ minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2.4cm, right =1 of fill]{Radio network controller};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm, ](fill2)[minimum height=1cm, below =1cm of rnc2]{};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](4)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, right =1 of fill2]{Node B};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](3)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, left =1 of fill2]{Node B};

            \node [rounded corners=3mm, ](fill3)[minimum height=1cm, below =1cm of rnc1]{};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](2)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, right =1 of fill3]{Node B};
            \node [rounded corners=3mm, fill=mycolor=!80](1)[minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2.4cm, left =1 of fill3]{Node B};
            \node [label=below:User equipement] (pc)[below= 1cm of fill3]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b} };
            \node [label=below:User equipement] (phone)[below= 1cm of fill2]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
            \draw[thick,->](cn)--node[]{}(rnc1);
            \draw[thick,->](cn)--node[]{}(rnc2);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc1)--node[]{}(1);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc1)--node[]{}(2);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc2)--node[]{}(3);
            \draw[thick,->](rnc2)--node[]{}(4);
            \draw[thick,->](1)--node[]{}(pc);
            \draw[thick,->](4)--node[]{}(phone);

            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
%             \path (rnc1) -- (1) coordinate[pos=0.95](aux1) (2) coordinate (aux2) (rnc1) coordinate (aux3)
%             (rnc1) coordinate (aux4) (3) coordinate (aux5) (4) coordinate (aux6);
%             \node[fill=blue!20,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,draw,
%             fit=(aux1) (aux2) (aux3)]{};
%             \node[fill=gray!20,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,draw,
%             fit=(aux4) (aux5) (aux6)]{};
              \node[fill=blue!20,draw,thick,fit=(rnc1)(1)(2),inner sep=-5mm]{};
              \node[fill=gray!20,draw,thick,fit=(rnc2)(3)(4),inner sep=-5mm]{};
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was hopping to something more like this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VvNi.png
But the rectangles behind, and automatically fitting if I move the nodes.
Like explained in this answer : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457729/drawing-network-schema

Comment: @Warok I updated my answer. Is that closer to what you wanted?

Comment: I will try with your solution, thanks for the help :)